# total commander ignoring svn folders on ftp upload

Tags: svn, ftp, total-commander

When I upload a folder that has ".svn" subfolders to ftp, the ".svn" folders are uploaded too. is it possible to make total commander ignore ".svn" folders when uploading to ftp?
I'd rather not use "export" option in the svn, because I have to upload new files very often and exporting takes time, so it's very inconvenient...

Comment: This strikes me as having decided on a solution without having described the root problem. *Why* are you uploading a working copy to an FTP server? Deployment? Backup? Are you also uploading directories which *aren't* part of a working copy? If you're doing it to back up your repository, and you're able to create a backup repo on your FTP server, you could use `svnsync` to keep your repositories in sync.

Comment: For deployment. There are slight changes to the project very often and I have to upload changed files to the FTP.

Answer (score 8):

There is a filter box between the local folder address and the remote folder address. In there type in `*.*|.svn\`

Comment: A had some problems with synchronization of large amount of files on tls encrypted connection. Now i copy stuff by hand :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse there's a File/Export action which allows you to export the project to file system. It's going to strip all .svn folders and other IDE/project related files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can solve the problem with Total Commander but here is a different solution: You should export your stuff from the repository with `svn export PATH1 PATH2` (see [documentation)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html). The exported version does not contain any svn meta data (like the .svn folders).

Comment: "I'd rather not use "export" option in the svn"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can do that with total commander, but I do know you can do this with Filezilla. You go to view->filename filters (or ctrl-i) and select CVS and SVN directories under the local filters. Now you can upload stuff to the server without having the CVS or SVN files uplaoded:)